# How to set one bar in one row only(with grouped row label) in Google TimeLine chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Hi im currently new to google timeline chart, and i have a question. Just like title how can i set one row only contain one row, but with grouped row label ?. Currently my problem is the image below, you can see TestA and TestB are in the same row :

[image: [problem](https://i.ibb.co/8sfw9R5/download.png)]

and here is what i want, TestA and TestB are in different row and the label are grouped :

[image: neededtobesolved]

here is the data of my chart :

```
dataTable.addRows([
  ["Washington", "TestA", new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
  ["Washington", "TestB", new Date(1798, 3, 30), new Date(1825, 2, 4)],
  ["Adams", "TestA", new Date(1797, 2, 4), new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
  ["Adams", "TestA", new Date(1789, 2, 4), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
  ["Jefferson", "TestA", new Date(1801, 2, 4), new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
]);
var options = {
  timeline: {
    groupByRowLabel: true
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as your chart options:

```js
const options = {
  timeline: { showRowLabels: false, groupByRowLabel: true },
  avoidOverlappingGridLines: true
};
```